# Linux - Share local network only

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, internet

I have two ethernet cards on PC:

1. eno1: Connected to router ( getting internet connection
   network:`192.168.200.0`)
2. eno2: Connected to access point (to share my
       connection to others network:`192.168.100.0`)

How can I block the internet connection that shared to `eno2`  / `192.168.100.0` and allow only access to this network `192.168.200.0`

What i want is:
For example

- UserA: `192.168.200.100`
- UserB: `192.168.100.100`

**UserA** hava access to internet + can ping **userB**

**UserB** No access to internet, But can ping **userA**

My problem is that both users have internet access.

Comment: since you want .200.0 accessible to users in .100.0, except for internet access through it, you will have to block access to the gateway (router) IP when the traffic comes from .100.0. You can achieve this by blocking the single gateway IP in your linux router (incoming on eno2 destined for the gateway IP), or by using a LAN-side firewall on the router to drop all traffic from .100.0. The second option is probably easier if the gateway router supports it.

Comment: @FrankThomas I thought in the second option but the router dos not supports it, I'll try to do the first option as you suggested and get back with the results, Thanks.